# Elastic Beanstalk EBS NPM Bower install is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bower, npm-install

Having an issue with my EBS deployment. Getting this output everytime it tries to deploy the build.

Application deployment failed at 2018-07-02T02:46:14Z with exit status 1 and error: command npm_install_bower in .ebextensions/bower.config failed.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1430:32)
npm ERR! at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR! at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:1029:10)
npm ERR! at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:521:13)
npm ERR! at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:418:25)
npm ERR! at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR! at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR! at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0.
```

bower.config file is:

```
commands:
 get_sudo:
  command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers 
 npm_install:
  command: sudo yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
 npm_install_bower:
    command: sudo npm install -g bower
container_commands:
  01_bower_install:
    command: "export PATH=$PATH; $NODE_HOME/bin/node ./node_modules/bowe/bin/bower -V install --allow-root -F > /tmp/01_bower_install.log"
```

Tried it without 01_bower_install part as well but same result. Fails to deploy. Was working fine until 2 days ago on the instance and now showing:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

..on the URL.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours today on the same issue, bower would not be installed by npm and would not run. Eventually got it work as follows:

1) remove "bower" from package.json

2) here is my ebextension file that managed to install bower and run it, by making it a global command:

```
container_commands:
  install_bower:
    command: "export PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin; npm install bower -g; bower install --allow-root"
```

Cheers,
Z.

Comment: p.s. if you haven't installed the package in a while then there is yet another surprise by the bower guys - the repo has changed. You need to add the following line to .bowerrc to make it work:   "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"